# How to add class to all forms automatically?

Tags: theming

I want to add .form class to all Drupal forms.  How can I add class to all forms by overriding theme function?

Comment: For what possible reason? If you have a class on _every_ form there's nothing to distinguish one from another - so just use `form {}`'

Comment: i am using framework for making theme in drupal. So i need to add ui form class to every form.

Comment: @Clive for some mystic reason, Bootstrap theme requires it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_OR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'MY_CLASS';
}
```